# Powershell ISE crash when loading

Tags: powershell

I have encountered an error when trying to launch Powershell ISE. The launch starts with 'Loading' displayed in the splash panel, then a dialog box comes up with "An unexpected error has occurred, and Windows PowerShell ISE must close"
I have Googled this error and come up with nothing specific, but I have followed a few steps that have been suggested for fixing other issues.

```
Platform: Windows 8.1 Pro

Powershell ISE product version: 10.0.14409.1005 

(Cannot open shell so cannot run cmdlet to get exect version details)
```

Things I have tried

```
1 The plain Powershell shell **does** launch.    
2 Tried launching ISE with -NoProfile & -MTA switches no luck    
3 Rename powershel_ise.exe.config so it cannot be read in both System32 & WOW64 folders    
4 Upgrade .NET Framework to 4.5.1    
5 Upgrade Management Framework to 5.1    
6 Other machines within our environment with same image and patch level have **not** encountered this problem    
7 Cannot find an associated error in the Event viewer logs
```

I really don't want to blow the machine away and start again so any suggestions or fix would be appreciated !

Angus

Comment: You have a few options.
1. Start **procmon** from sysinternals, start ISE, stop **procmon** and search voor access denied messages *(most likely culprit)*
2. Install **procdump** as the postmortem debugger and analyze the dumps
3. Run **procdump** and dump on first chance exceptions. Something like `procdump -ma -e 1 -n 100 -w powershell_ise`
4. Start the ise through Windbg

Comment: If the above won't help, I would try uninstalling all .NET frameworks using .NET uninstaller tool, which you can find online, then reinstall .NET and WMF.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I have tried the PCMON and have not found an access denied message. I have tried the PC dump and found that it cannot find a DLL in the v3 directory however if I navigate to that directory it is there

Comment: @w0xx0m I have run the uninstallers from the 'programs control panel' which showed the frameworks were uninstalled, went to reinstall and was told that the framework was already installed, however tools such as Atlassian Source Tree won't run now, Frameworks gone but registy entries still present. Would you know which keys I need to remove from the registry to re install ?

Comment: @GusD - Is that DLL in the procmon trace? Can you share the trace and/or dump?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, I was able to fix it with recreating my user profile.

You can log as different user and try to run powershell_ise in that profile, if it runs, so more likely you can fix it. Just have somebody with admin rights delete your profile, and then just log back. Or if you have admin rights go create another account with admin, go to system properties / user profiles and remove your current profile ( just save files you need to keep)

Comment: Wow this has come back to life, however too late as i blew the entire machine aware and reinstalled from scratch.....Damm !

Comment: Are you talking about you Windows Profile??  What Profile are you referring to?

Comment: I renamed the C:\Users\<name>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell directory and re-ran ISE and it didn't crash. Something up with that profile directory for me...

Answer (score 0):

"I renamed the C:\Users<name>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell directory and re-ran ISE and it didn't crash. Something up with that profile directory for me... –
Duncan Smart
Feb 10 '21 at 11:07"

Solved my similar issue! :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Documents C:\Users<loggedinProfileName>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell and re name from WindowsPowerShell to Old_WindowsPowerShell it will work if its crashes because for user profile.