# powershell_ise stopped working on Server 2008 R2

Tags: crash, powershell-ise

I have the same issue as this person:

[Powershell ISE crash when loading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44916042/1630171)

Logging in as a different user does not help. When I try to run powershell_ise - with or without `-MTA -NoProfile` - it comes up with a window saying "powershell_ise has stopped working." Clicking on the "Check online for a solution and close the program" just closes the program. Problem details gives:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   PowerShell
  NameOfExe:    powershell_ise.exe
  FileVersionOfSystemManagementAutomation:  10.0.14409.1012
  InnermostExceptionType:   System.IO.FileFormatException
  OutermostExceptionType:   System.Reflection.TargetInvocation
  DeepestPowerShellFrame:   indows.PowerShell.GuiExe.Internal.GPowerShell.Main
  DeepestFrame: System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod
  ThreadName:   unknown
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.274.10
  Locale ID:    5129

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy
statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

I have tried for days to find something on line and can find nothing. I have deleted the `powershell_ise.exe.config` file - same deal.
It's a server (2008 R2) and does a lot of stuff. Recreating it would be a real pain! Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: What is the output of `$PSVersionTable` in a PowerShell console? Do you get the same behavior for the 32-bit version as well? Do you see any related errors in the eventlog? What was the last thing you changed on the machine before ISE stopped working?

Comment: Name                      Value                  
----                      -----                  
PSVersion                 5.1.14409.1012         
PSEdition                 Desktop                
PSCompatibleVersions      {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion              10.0.14409.1012        
CLRVersion                4.0.30319.42000        
WSManStackVersion         3.0                    
PSRemotingProtocolVersion 2.3                    
SerializationVersion      1.1.0.1                


Yes, 32-bit does the same.

Comment: The last thing I changed was upgrading to 5.1 and .net 4 - but it continued to work fine after that for several weeks.  Makes me wonder if some Windows update changed it.  It is up to date.

Comment: PS - eventlog does show  stuff - but too long to paste here - 640 character limit

Comment: as much as I can put in from log:Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: PowerShell
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: PowerShell_ISE.exe
P2: 10.0.14409.1012
P3: System.IO.FileFormatException
P4: System.Reflection.TargetInvocation
P5: indows.PowerShell.GuiExe.Internal.GPowerShell.Main
P6: System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod
P7: unknown
P8: 
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\admjjen009\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\Critical_PowerShell_ISE.e_ca38d3d44b6785edb544e362173a1eb984114e3_11444375

Comment: event log dumps a .wer file but it just says the same stuff as the pop-up error shows.

Comment: \Microsoft\Windows\Powershell event logs don't show anything that looks related.

Comment: I had a similar issue.
I installed fixittool-KB4074906.exe from [Windows Update](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=4074906) and the issue gone.